# set init params to jsp page without web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I know that I can set init params for a jsp page using web.xml. For example

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>init</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/init.jsp</jsp-file>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>test</param-name>
      <param-value>me</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>init</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/init.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then in my init.jsp I can get the init params using getServletContext.getInitParameter..

However, I am using WebSevlet 3.0 annotations and I can't see equivalent jsp-file annotation. I am looking for something along these lines

```
@WebServlet(initParams=@WebInitParam(name="hello", value = "hello"),description = "A Simple Servlet", urlPatterns = { "/init.jsp" })
```

where I can use jsp-file annotation. So I need to set the jsp init params without using web.xml.

Answer (score -1):

I know you said without using a web.xml - but you could still use a web.xml file with annotations - and just use it for the parameters - define the init params as a context-param.  That would set the parameter for the whole application...

```
   <context-param>
      <param-name>someParameter</param-name>
      <param-value>someValue</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

Then in your code - reference it in the same way as above :

```
    getServletContext.getInitParameter("someParameter");
```

Comment: I don't web.xml file at all